# Config RegexField's just accept hyphen (-) and numbers only - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hope your guys help me Config RegexField's just accept hyphen (-) and numbers only in Django Rest Framework

Now I config:

`username = RegexField(regex=r'^[\d-]+$', required=True, max_length=50)`

My serializers:

```
class UserSignUpSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = RegexField(regex=r'^[\d-]+$', required=True, max_length=50)
    email = EmailField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    password = CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password'
        ]
    extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}
```

It's not work!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: It also accept others character like `abc@sad!dasd`

Comment: Try this -    ^[a-z-0-9A-z]+$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That regular expression allows any alphanumeric character (`a to z`, `A to Z`, and `0 to 9`).

You are looking for:

```
# \d         allows only numeric digits
# - or \-    allows only hyphen
# [\d-]      allows a single character, either a digit or a hyphen
# [\d-]+     allows for more than one character, but a minimum of one is required
# ^[\d-]+$   the whole input string must match the regular expression   
RegexField(regex=r'^[\d-]+$', required=True, max_length=50)
```

Comment: I reconfig but `asdad@asdasd-ad+asd` is also acceptable!

Comment: @FeedGit Are you saying that the example you provided should be allowed, or that it is currently allowed and shouldn't?

Comment: I updated my serializers above. If I enter `asdad@asdasd-ad+asd` in username field, it is acceptable!

Comment: @FeedGit What exactly do you mean by acceptable? I have no experience at Django, but as far as I know it'll let you type anything you want on the text field. However, it'll fail validation when submitting

Comment: I want acceptable just: number (0-9), Alphabet (a-z, A-Z) and hyphen (-) also.

Comment: @KitKit you need to add the letters to the class like this `r'^[\d\-a-zA-Z]+$'`